# Casting a Object into Reflected Class and Method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, reflection

A normal form of what I am trying is this.

```
MyClassFacadeLocal cls = new MyClassFacadeLocal();
List allMyClass = cls.findAll();
Iterator it = allMyClass.iterator();
while(it.haxNext()) {
    MyClass Obj = (MyClass)it.next();
    out.println(obj.getTitle());
}
```

Now, the problem I am creating a global method, which can handle several cases of this. For this, I will pass the Entity Class name, method name and the List that is return by the `.findAll()` method. How to solve this using the reflection. What I tried was really rough and of course didn't work.

```
List allMyClass; //I will have passed this before
Iterator it = allMyClass.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {

    try {
        Class<?> c = Class.forName(this.getEntityClassName());
        c.cast(it.next());
        Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod("getTitle");
        String title = method.invoke(c, null).toString();
    } catch(Exception e) {
    }

}
```

Gives: `"object is not an instance of declaring class"` error. But I am confident this is a usage flaw.

Comment: I am a Noob in java, so please silly mistakes are abundant. :)

Comment: Really, you shouldn't use reflection to do that. Make all your entities implement a common interface with a getTitle() method.

Comment: @JBNizet, Could you show a small example of how to do this?

Comment: @JBNizet, I know what to create a interface and implement the common method. I just need help with the implementation part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really, you shouldn't use reflection to do that. Make all your entities implement a common interface with a `getTitle()` method:

```
public interface HasTitle {
    public String getTitle();
}

public class MyClass1 implements HasTitle {
    // ...

    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }
}

public class MyClass2 implements HasTitle {
    // ...

    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }
}

...

/**
 * This method can be invoked withg a List<MyClass1> or with a List<MyClass2>
 * as argument, since MyClass1 and MyClass2 both implement HasTitle
 */
public void displayTitles(List<? extends HasTitle> entities) {
    for (HasTitle entity : entities) {
        out.println(entity.getTitle();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first glance flaw I see is that you don't assign the

```
c.cast(it.next());
```

to new variable.

Comment: Assign to what, I dont know the class name, that is where I want to use the reflection.

Comment: if you are casting with "c" it is obviously Class<?> that comes out.
Use the answer below or, as otherwise suggested, don't use reflection at all, it's very often bad choice as it circumvents Java's compile time checks

Answer (score 0):

Your code does too much work by using `Class.forName` and uses the wrong reflection method `getDeclaredMethod` -- that one doesn't take into account the inherited methods. The `c.cast` line doesn't do anything -- it merely asserts that the object is an instance of its own class.

Use this code:

```
public static void printProp(List<?> xs, String methodName) {
  try {
    for (Object x : xs)
      System.out.println(x.getClass().getMethod(methodName).invoke(x));
  } catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
}
```